# How can i booked and also check room booked for twice in single day (early checkout)

Tags: sql, mysql

While preparing report how can i check same room is reserved for twice daily, for example
Room A booking time from 10 am to next day 10am but if user checkout early then same room booked twice, so how can locate that?

| SR | BKNO | Start_date | End_date | R.No | End_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 31-12-2023 | 01-01-2024 | 101 | 24:00 |
| 2 | A2 | 31-12-2023 | 01-01-2024 | 101 | 10:00 |
| 3 | A3 | 01-01-2024 | 03-01-2024 | 101 | 10:00 |
| 4 | A4 | 31-12-2023 | 02-01-2024 | 102 | 15:00 |
| 5 | A5 | 02-01-2024 | 02-01-2024 | 102 | 10:00 |

In above example A2 person will stay in room for only few hours from 24:00 to 10:00 morning means total 9 hours (Early Checkout) Similarly A4 booking also checkout early and another person occupy room after 15:00 of room no 102.

I wanted to locate early checkout and room booked twice as day in both cases for Room No 101 & 102.

I tried Mysql query

```
((checkin <= '01-01-2024' AND checkout >= '01-01-2024') OR
(checkin <= '01-01-2024' AND checkout >= '01-01-2024') OR
(checkin >= '01-01-2024' AND checkout <= '01-01-2024'))
```

When i am searching daily occupancy room status with above query i got 2 records of room no. 101 of booking no A1,A2 & A3  which is correct and when i say distinct i got only one records, here i suppose to get only 2records that is A1 & A2 and i count it and say 101 room occupancy is more then 100% because it booked 2 times in a single day.

How can i get those result can anyone help me in this regards

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way to go about this is to create a new table 'dates' which contains dates from some big range like 1999 to 2100

```
date
2012-01-01
2012-01-02
2012-01-03
.
.
```

then query by joining your booking table with this dates table like:

```
Select count(*) as booking_number, b.room_no,d.date from bookings b
join dates d on d.date between b.start_date and b.end_date
where d.date = '2024-01-01'
group by b.room_no, d.date 
having booking_number > 1
```

Comment: I want know the query through that i come to know that R.No 101 is booked 2 times on date 2024-01-01, in daily occupancy reports

Comment: Create a temperary dates table and add "where d.date = '2024-01-01' and b.room_no = 101" in the query ?

Comment: Creating temporary dates tables is feasible? because there almost 4 yrs data, and everytime doing that is i think not the way, perhaps i have tried using group by R.no and Endtime and its giving me result, but still i would like the way other from experts.